# Getting slow while selecting the data in data base in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 10 million of data we insert daily.when we using select operation it takes too much of time what is best solution.i am using MySQL 5.6

Comment: Have you added index on fields which are getting used in "where" condition?

Comment: you  use  limit in you mysql query like select * from table_name LIMIT 0, 10; and  select * from table_name LIMIT 11, 20;

Comment: Also if insertion happening once in a day, you can use external caching or you can enable MySQL cache

Comment: Have a look at partioning

Comment: There are few factors to consider (i.e, server specs, table normalization, indexing, etc.). Can you provide the schema(s) just to rule out poor table design? Please also indicate the server specs.